# Extracting a specific word using Regex in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to extract the name of the country from the following dataframe

```
country
0   NaN
1   Country: America
2   Country: France ...More CountriesFranceNorwayP...
3   NaN
4   Country: India
```

using the following regex statement

```py
import re
regex = re.compile(\
    r"Country: (?P<country>\w+)"
    )

df['country'] = df['country'].str.extractall(regex).droplevel(1)
```

However it returns

```
country
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
```

Instead of returning

```
country
0   NaN
1   America
2   France
3   NaN
4   India
```

What am I missing out on?

Please Advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extract`:

```py
df['country'] = df['country'].str.extract(r'Country:\s*(\w+)')
```

Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'country' : [np.nan, 'Country: America', 'Country France ... More countries...']})
df['country'].str.extract(r'Country:\s*(\w+)')
#          0
# 0      NaN
# 1  America
# 2      NaN
```

Comment: Works great! Any reason as to why my statement was returning NaN?

Comment: @Luke I am not sure what the reason could be, I do not see the whole data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid `regex` and use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
In [86]: df = pd.DataFrame({'country' : [np.nan, 'Country: America', 'Country: France ... More countries...', np.nan, 'Country: India']})

In [87]: df
Out[87]: 
                                 country
0                                    NaN
1                       Country: America
2  Country: France ... More countries...
3                                    NaN
4                         Country: India

In [94]: df.country.str.split(':').str[1].str.split().str[0]
Out[94]: 
0        NaN
1    America
2     France
3        NaN
4      India
Name: country, dtype: object
```

Comment: Definitely tried it! Works as good as regex! but I'm not sure if it has worked all the way

Comment: Assumption in the answer is based on the way your sample data is. Might need to tweak it a bit on your full data.